# Density function of a sum of 75 discrete random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need help with find the density function of $S$ if

$$S=\sum_1^{75}X_j,$$

where $X_j=I_jB_j$, and $I_1,\ldots, I_{75},B_1,\ldots, B_{75} $ are independent,

$$Pr(I_j=1)=0.01 , \  Pr(I_j=0)=0.99 \ \ \mbox{ for all } j,$$

$$Pr(B_j=50)=0.7, Pr(B_j=100)=0.3 \ \ \mbox{ for } 1 \leq j \leq 50$$
and 
$$Pr(B_j=75)=0.7, Pr(B_j=150)=0.3 \ \ \mbox{ for } 51\leq j \leq 75$$

I think that maybe I have to calculate convolutions, but that is a tedious job and I don't know how could I progam that in python, for example. Is there an easier way to calculate the density function of S?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to show exact form of this pdf, or just program it in python?

Comment: I have to show a exact form of this pdf, but I can program it in python.

Comment: Are $\ I_j, B_j\ $ all indepenent?

Comment: yes, they are independent

Comment: @Minysh: I've added an answer that I hope that can help you. I can add more information to it, but I would need to understand better what do you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by density function in this context, because I think about the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) which is for continuous variables and here your outcome $X_j$ is discrete, therefore, the sum $S$ of $X_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq 75$ will also be discrete.

However, I can give some suggestions about the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), which is a similar concept but for discrete variables.

We can begin by looking for the probability mass function of $X_j$. I think it's better to start by analysing the problem in two parts, $1$ to $50$ and then $51$ to $75$. Then compute the possible products $I_j B_j$. In this case we will have:

For $1 \leq j \leq 50$:
$$
\begin{align}
& I_j B_j = 1 \times 50  & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.01 \times 0.7 \\
& I_j B_j = 1 \times 100 & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.01 \times 0.3 \\
& I_j B_j = 0 \times 50  & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.99 \times 0.7 \\
& I_j B_j = 0 \times 100 & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.99 \times 0.3
\end{align}
$$
And for $51 \leq j \leq 75$:
$$
\begin{align}
& I_j B_j = 1 \times 75  & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.01 \times 0.7 \\
& I_j B_j = 1 \times 150 & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.01 \times 0.3 \\
& I_j B_j = 0 \times 75  & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.99 \times 0.7 \\
& I_j B_j = 0 \times 150 & \textrm{with} \quad Pr = 0.99 \times 0.3
\end{align}
$$

Can you construct the probability mass function $P(X_j=x)$ from this data?

---

**Edit:** Just for fun, here is $P(X_j=x)$:
$$
P(X_j=x)
\begin{cases}
0.990 & \textrm{if} & x=0 \\
0.007 & \textrm{if} & x=50 \wedge 1 \leq j \leq 50 \\
0.007 & \textrm{if} & x=75 \wedge 51 \leq j \leq 75 \\
0.003 & \textrm{if} & x=100 \wedge 1 \leq j \leq 50 \\
0.003 & \textrm{if} & x=150 \wedge 51 \leq j \leq 75 \\
0     & & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

And we can split the sums in two parts. Since the distribution in each part is [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), we get  (if I'm not mistaken):
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{50} X_j = \sum_{j=0}^{50} \sum_{k=0}^{50-j} (50j + 100k) \times \frac{50!}{j! \cdot k! \cdot (50-j-k)!} \times 0.007^j \times 0.003^k \times 0.990^{50-j}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=51}^{75} X_j = \sum_{j=0}^{25} \sum_{k=0}^{25-j} (75j + 150k) \times \frac{25!}{j! \cdot k! \cdot (25-j-k)!} \times 0.007^j \times 0.003^k \times 0.990^{50-j}
$$

Comment: Thank you. I used python to calculate the coefficients of the probability generating function of $S$ and so get the probability $P(S=s)$.

Comment: You're welcome, @Minysh. Just for fun, I added $P(X_j=x). :)